Flutter Google Sign In not getting user Google name - Firestore
I would like to get the user's email and fullname for the Google sign in but for some reason I have not been able to get the user's name. Can you please let me know how it can be fixed?
   signInWithGoogle() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
        await googleUser?.authentication;
    var credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
    );
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential).then((value) {
      final user = value.user!;
      setState(() {
        id = user.uid; name = user.displayname;
        email = user.email ?? 'a@gmail.com';
      });
      value.additionalUserInfo!.isNewUser
          ? FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("users")
              .doc(
                id,
              )
              .set({
              'email': email, 'name': name,
            })
          : null;
    })
  }

The name value should get user's google name from "user" or "additionalUserInfo" value but for some reason I get "Guest user" optional name in the database after signing up the new user. I tried both of these options...

I recommend using value.user! both for setting the name state variable as for writing to the database:
final user = value.user!;
setState(() {
  name = user.displayName;
});
FirebaseFirestore.instance
     .collection("usertable")
     .doc(user.uid)
     .set({
         'email': user.email,
         'fullname': user.displayName,
       });


sure @Frank! That sounds good. Displayname is still calling my optional value for some reason. It wouldn't grab the google name...

It works for me here: https://z124069j1250.zapp.page/#/ (lots of problems in the popup, but it does get the display name from my Google account in the end)

Thanks @Frank. I updated my code in my original message. Now it seems to work on my phone before pushing to Google Play console but when I push it to Internal Testing in the Google Play Console, it fails creating the user. Not sure why there is inconsistency there. Did you have the Flutter code somewhere for your project you mentioned?

Added the SHA1 key in Google Play. Now this is resolved...
